# Tile background using diamond shape?

Tags: android

I am creating a tiled background. I read may posts about using bitmap xml with repeat tile. The tile I am using is has a diamond shape. So when I do the tile there are black gaps in between the tiles.

I hope  I am explaining myself. How can this be done so the whole screen is covered tiles (ie sides touching each other not only vertices)
Thank you

I am using this image
[image]

And this is the code

```
<bitmap
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/tile"
android:tileMode="repeat"
android:dither="true" />
```

Comment: What I got from your question is, you want to fill entire background using this tile and you don't want blank space on the background. Right?

Comment: yes that is exactly it

Comment: Then why don't you put square image instead of diamond?

Comment: Because the above image I used is a sample. The real Dimond I am using is multi colored and have rough edges. So making it as a square will change the look of the tiling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to achieve is **impossible** yet.

Images are **always rectangle shaped**. You see it as diamond just because **corners of image are transparent**. But it still has rectangle shape.

This is what **actual image** should look like,

[image]

But black corners are not visible because it has **transparency set at the corners**. That's why it looks like,

[image]

If your image had **no transparency** then your **tiled background** would look like,

[image]

And because of transparency at the corners it is looking like,

[image]

And what try to achieve is to **overlap that blank space** with diamond (because you say image is diamond shaped) which is not possible because images are **always in rectangular shape**.

And there's no library written yet which can **ignore the alpha** (transparency) of the image.

You should either use **opaque image** or leave the space blank in tiled background (if you use this image).

Comment: @Snake as I suggested before, you need to use square shaped image to fill entire background.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps change the way you are tiling your image? Maybe your initial image that you're tiling looks like this `<>` but maybe you want it to look like this `><` ? It would be more helpful if you posted your image. Can you also post the code you're using to tile the bitmap?

Comment: Thank you, please see edit to the question. Maybe you can further ellaborate?

Comment: You know with the image you provided that the diamonds wouldn't touch right? The diamond doesn't touch the edge of the image. Maybe that's the issue you're having? Unless you get black gaps in the form of a grid surrounding the square image. Could you post a screenshot of what you're seeing as well?

Comment: Hmmm not quite sure I get. If you take the above diamond and put another one beside it. Then that would make a pair. Then put another pair under that pair, you will have 4 diamond but the middle is an empty black Diamond. How can I fill that black Diamond in the middle with the image above